# SQL query to convert no. of rows to no. of column in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, pivot

I need to convert all rows into columns i.e. no.of columns= total no. of values in col2 and col3 related to col1.

**Scenario**

[image]

**Query tried:**

```
with cte as (
    select 'A' as col1, 1 as col2, 2 as col3 from dual
    union
    select 'A' as col1, 3 as col2, 4 as col3 from dual
    union
    select 'A' as col1, 5 as col2, 6 as col3 from dual
    union
    select 'B' as col1, 10 as col2, 101 as col3 from dual
    union
    select 'B' as col1, 20 as col2, 202 as col3 from dual
    union
    select 'C' as col1, 50 as col2, 501 as col3 from dual
    union
    select 'C' as col1, 60 as col2, 601 as col3 from dual
    union
    select 'C' as col1, 70 as col2, 701 as col3 from dual
) select * from cte
```

How can I write a pivot query here?

Comment: The answer you accepted does not actually generate the output you are expecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `row_number()` and conditional aggregation

```
select col1,
       max(case when rn=1 then col2 end) as col2,
       max(case when rn=2 then col2 end) as col3,
       max(case when rn=3 then col2 end) as col4,
       max(case when rn=1 then col3 end) as col5,
       max(case when rn=2 then col3 end) as col6,
       max(case when rn=3 then col3 end) as col7
from
(
select *, row_number() over(partition by col1 order by null) as rn
from tablename
)A group by col1
```

Comment: I could not understand.why down voted this ans ? Is there any wrong here ? Explanation much more apprreciated

Answer (score 1):

One approach to handle this uses a pivot query along with `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Col1 ORDER BY Col2) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT
    Col1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN Col2 END) AS Col2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN Col3 END) AS Col3,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN Col2 END) AS Col4,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN Col3 END) AS Col5,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN Col2 END) AS Col6,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN Col3 END) AS Col7
FROM cte
GROUP BY
    Col1;
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: this won't work if 1 more row is added to the data. Can't we make it dynamic ?

Comment: @Deep Yes, but you would likely have to use dynamic Oracle SQL, which basically means writing some code which itself generates the query you want.

Comment: Yes, apart from PL/SQL can we do that? Like as you have written code in Oracle SQL. So is it possible? As I am trying and not able to make it work. I used Listagg first to make the whole string and then want to split them using REGEX but in that scenario also I have to tell the number of columns. So is there a way that it can create dynamic columns based on data? `SELECT  LISTAGG(col2 || ':' || col3,':') WITHIN GROUP (order by COL1) list , count(*) *2 num
from cte group by col1`

Answer (score 1):

```
-- Oracle 11g+: pivot
with cte as  (
select 'A' as col1, 1  as col2, 2   as col3 from dual union all
select 'A' as col1, 3  as col2, 4   as col3 from dual union all
select 'A' as col1, 5  as col2, 6   as col3 from dual union all
select 'B' as col1, 10 as col2, 101 as col3 from dual union all
select 'B' as col1, 20 as col2, 202 as col3 from dual union all
select 'C' as col1, 50 as col2, 501 as col3 from dual union all
select 'C' as col1, 60 as col2, 601 as col3 from dual union all
select 'C' as col1, 70 as col2, 701 as col3 from dual )
select *
from
   (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by col1 order by col2) rn
    from cte t
   )
pivot (max(col2) as pc2, max(col3) as pc3 for rn in (1,2,3));

C      1_PC2      1_PC3      2_PC2      2_PC3      3_PC2      3_PC3
- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
A          1          2          3          4          5          6
B         10        101         20        202
C         50        501         60        601         70        701
```